# verify license before start pyqt main window

Tags: python, pyqt5, verify

I'm working in desktop app using pyqt5
I need to make online check for the license before opening the app or enabling the functions
What is the best way to do this,
I tried the QProgressDialog but it seems that the client can close it and pass to the app
also I customize a frameless window but ALT F4 closing it and also pass to the app

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share the best solution I found for this case (it may help some one)

in the main window I created a new label, I called it verify
it should shown in the middle of the window when the app open
it have a message like: verifying please wait
I also disable all the app buttons

Now when we start the app, I will run the verify function on external qthread, some thing like this:

```
    # verifyClass thread
    verifyInstance = verifyClass()
    verifyInstance.sig.connect(self.verify_func)
    thread = QThread()
    self._v_thread = (thread, verifyInstance)
    verifyInstance.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.started.connect(verifyInstance.verify_func)
    thread.start()
```

and the verify class should be some thing like this:

```
## verifyClass
class verifyClass(QObject):
    sig = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    @pyqtSlot()
    def verify_func(self):
        ## your verification code
        self.sig.emit(1) ## mean the verification is okay, do it if verification success
```

and in the mainWin Class you should have this function:

```
def verify_func(self,i):
    if i == 1:
        self.ui.verify.hide()
        ## enable your buttons
```

and this way my code is organized and controllable for many cases